# TSQL DateDiff to return number of days with 2 decimal places

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to compare 2 dates and return the number of days in between with 2 decimal places.

For example:

when comparing

```
SubmittedDate = 2012-02-29 07:02:55.000

FirstCall = 2012-02-29 12:12:19.000
```

That is a 5 hour difference. So I would return 0.2 days

I have tried:

```
CAST(DATEDIFF(Hour, SubmittedDate, FirstCall)/30.0 AS DECIMAL(5,2)) As HoursBeforeFirstCall
CAST(DATEDIFF(Day, SubmittedDate, FirstCall) AS DECIMAL(5,2)) As HoursBeforeFirstCall
```

None seem to work.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Take the `DateDiff` in seconds instead, and then divide by `86400.0`. The decimal point is required.

Comment: This works great. Is there a way I can get it down to 2 decimal places

Comment: You could try this for 2 decimal places (not saying it's the most efficient in terms of performance): SELECT CAST((DATEDIFF(s,'2018-07-01 09:00 AM',GETDATE()) / 86400.0) AS DECIMAL(6,2))

Comment: This can come with a nasty surprise of an overflow error if your diff is greater than 24,855 days (which is roughly 68 years).

Answer (score 11):

When you represent a date as a number, each day is represented by 1.0 "units" already.  To get the timespan of two dates as a decimal, you can just subtract them.

```
SELECT CAST((@FirstCall - @SubmittedDate) AS NUMERIC(10, 2))
```

Comment: If someone is going to use this method, I believe you'd want to divide by `365.2425`

Comment: @daveomcd Why?  The question is asking for the time span in days, not years and I don't think your calculation would be accurate for most cases, anyway.

Comment: My apologies missed the part about days I guess... why wouldn't it be correct for years though?

Comment: @daveomcd Well, if you were to calculate the difference between '2015-01-01 00:00:00.000' and '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000', I think most people would expect the "number of years" to be 1.00, not some fraction of that value.  Your divisor is probably best used for estimating the difference between two very different dates (spanning multiple years).  If you wanted a more accurate calculation for years, I'd calculate the number of full years since the first date + (number of days in the last year)/(number of days in that year)

Comment: Fair enough, yes the case I came across was calculating a person's age (17+) in decimals.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: Beware subtracting only works with the older `datetime` datatype; it will raise an error when using newer date types such as `datetime2`, `datetimeoffset`, etc. ([which by the way you should](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql).) For this reason alone `DATEDIFF` is preferable as it works across the board.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I've done:

```
ROUND(SUM(DATEDIFF(ss,StartDateTime,EndDateTime) / 60.0 / 60.0), 2)
```

Comment: This gives hours not days.

Answer (score 1):

How about this.

```
select convert(decimal(12,2),convert(decimal(12,2),datediff(second,'2012-02-29 07:02:55.000','2012-02-29 12:12:19.000'))/60/60/24)
```