# How to convert Time to Decimal in SQL with an integer

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, decimal

I am having a couple of issues converting time to decimal...

Essentially I have used a DATEDIFF to identify the hours and minutes between two dates and times. This produces a result of 5.45, however I would like to get the result as 5.75.

```
select RTRIM(DATEDIFF(second, startdate, enddate)/3600)+'.'
+ RIGHT('0'+RTRIM((DATEDIFF(second, startdate, enddate) % 3600)/60),2)
from time
```

I have tried a few things but I believe the issue is that this is not an integer and that's why i cant convert the minutes.

Comment: This does not seem like a duplicate of the thread above, as that thread talks about "whole days difference" while the question above is about formatting the "hours and minutes difference".

Answer (score 2):

Get the time difference in minutes, and divide by 60, this will place hours before the decimal separator and minutes after:

```
datediff(minute, startdate, enddate) / 60.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select DATEDIFF(second,  startdate, enddate)/3600.0
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9524175/104223), "Take the DateDiff in seconds instead, and then divide by 86400.0. The decimal point is required."

Comment: That returns days like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9524175/104223) but it sounds like he wants hours and minutes.