# How to convert mysql time

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, converters

My time in mysql is in the form hh:mm:ss
How can I convert that to 12 hour time and also remove the seconds, because they are all 00.

ex:

```
14:30:00
```

mysql

```
$finalresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE clubID IN (" . implode(',', $clubIDs) . ") ORDER BY date ASC, TIME(startTime) ASC");

while($finalrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($finalresult)) {

$originaltime = $finalrow['startTime'];
$newtime = TIME_FORMAT($originaltime, '%h:%i %p');

}
```

Comment: This is really a basic question. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: this might help you find what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13616672/how-to-convert-time-to-decimal-in-sql-with-an-integer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [TIME_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format):

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT('14:30:00', '%h:%i %p'); /* 02:30 PM */
```

---

Change your PHP to something like this:

```
$finalresult = mysql_query("SELECT Field1, Field2, TIME_FORMAT(DateField, '%h:%i %p') AS TheTime FROM events WHERE clubID IN (" . implode(',', $clubIDs) . ") ORDER BY date ASC, TIME(startTime) ASC");
```

This involves getting rid of `*` and specifying each field you want.

Comment: i am getting the error that time_format() function is undefined

Comment: $newtime = TIME_FORMAT($originaltime, '%h:%i %p');

Comment: `TIME_FORMAT` is a MySQL function, not a PHP function. I was unaware that you were using PHP.

Comment: how would i do that if i have a row, and im getting it like row['time'];

Comment: i am getting from mysql actually

Comment: What does your MySQL statement look like now? Can you add that to your question?

Comment: when i call it as $finalrow['time'] i get null

Comment: I should have added `AS TheTime`, or whatever you want to call it. That way you can say `$finalrow['TheTime']`. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a `TIME` type, you can use the [`TIME_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format) function.

To get the 12-hour time, without seconds:

```
TIME_FORMAT(myTime, '%h:%i')
```

A time of 14:24:38 will come out as `2:24`.

If you need the AM/PM designation now that you've converted to a 12-hour clock, simply add the `%p` format code:

```
TIME_FORMAT(myTime, '%h:%i %p')
```

For this, a time of 14:24:38 will come out as `2:24 PM`.

Comment: i am getting the error that time_format() function is undefined

Comment: $newtime = TIME_FORMAT($originaltime, '%h:%i %p');

Comment: Ah, I get it - the answer I gave is for MySQL, not for PHP. If you include the `TIME_FORMAT` function call in your MySQL query you won't need to convert/format in PHP.

Comment: how would i do that if i have a row, and im getting it like row['time'];

Comment: It would come before that. When you issue the query to MySQL, instead of something like `SELECT col1, col2, timeval FROM myTable` you'd query `SELECT col1, col2, TIME_FORMAT(timeval, '%h:%i') AS time FROM myTable`. The `AS time` will name the column `time` so you can reference it as `row['time']`.

Comment: Instead of starting the query as `SELECT * FROM events WHERE ...`, start with `SELECT *, TIME_FORMAT(startTime, '%h:%i') AS formattedStartTime FROM events WHERE ...`. Then, in your PHP, assign `$originalTime` like this: `$originaltime = $finalrow['formattedStartTime'];`. Also note that you should use mysqli or PDO for data retrieval; the "mysql" PHP driver will be going away because it's not secure.