# How to convert time type 50:45:55

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, time, casting

How to convert (in T-SQL) time type `40:30:00` (hh:mm:ss), to type `40.30` (decimal).

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: But `40:30:00` is forty and a half hour, wouldn't you expect the decimal representation to be `40.50`?

Comment: This is necessary to sum and other the calculations, To sum times work maschine  for example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert Time to Decimal in SQL with an integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13616672/how-to-convert-time-to-decimal-in-sql-with-an-integer)

Comment: Can you explain how you got a value of more than 40 hours into a [`TIME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) with a range of 00:00:00.0000000 through 23:59:59.9999999?

Comment: I know that types Timea is between 00:00:00 and 23:59:59. I found solution. Time used in project is quantity second. 

Enough were divide quantity second by (3600.0)

Problem is solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below query if you want to convert time to decimal :

```
DECLARE @Col DATETIME  = '23:30:00'
SELECT cast(datepart(hour, @Col) + datepart(minute, @Col) / 100.00 as 
decimal(5, 2))  

For Larger value :

DECLARE @Col VARCHAR(100) = '40:30:00'
DECLARE @Col1 BIGINT = CAST(REPLACE(@Col,':','') AS BIGINT)
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(12,2),@Col1)
```

Comment: Thank you.I used function datediff. 
select 
datediff(second, '0:0:0',
   '15'
+ ':' + '30'+ ':' + '00') /(60.0*60.0)

Comment: I need convrt value with bigger values.  50 hours for example.

Comment: @Krzysztof Suchecki,DATETIME have 24 hours format only.So you have bigger value means ie 50 or 60.You should change datatype

Comment: Yes. You're tight. What is it type? What I have to make?

Comment: Unfortunately, It's not ok. Result for me is "403000.00".

Comment: select  datediff(second,0,'11:05:00') / (60.0 * 60.0) correct result is 11.08333333 for example.

Comment: @Krzysztof Suchecki,with in 24 it's working fine.over 24 is not possible.

Comment: @Krzysztof Suchecki,how you get hh:mm:ss as 40:50:55..?