# DATEDIFF() to just return age with 2 decimal points

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SELECT statement requesting the age of he individual when a test was made:

```
SELECT
   DATEDIFF(dd,BIRTH_DATE,TEST_DATE)/365.25 [Age at Result]
FROM TABLE
WHERE ID = '100'
```

The result comes out like `2.056125`.

I saw on another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524094/tsql-datediff-to-return-number-of-days-with-2-decimal-places) to convert to seconds and divide by `86400.0`, but I was still getting 6 decimal points.

What I was looking back was to get the age as `2.05` or even round to `2.00`.

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to round a value for numeric calculations or how to format a value for display? As a rule, formatting should be left to application code, not handled in the database. Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: Added the tag. Will note that for future questions. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cast to a decimal with the precision you want:

```
SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(day, BIRTH_DATE, TEST_DATE)/365.25 as DECIMAL(10, 2)) as [Age at Result]
FROM TABLE
WHERE ID = 100;
```

Note:  I removed the single quotes around "100".  Only use single quotes if it the `id` is a string.

Comment: shouldn't it be "dd" instead of "date" as first parameter of DATEDIFF?

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, still had ' ' around the ID because the real case is a string.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following -

```
DECLARE @TestDate DATETIME = GETDATE()
DECLARE @BirthDate DATETIME = '1995-06-06 08:00:00.000'

SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(dd,@BirthDate,@TestDate)/365.25 AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) [Age at Result]
```